# Migrate Exchange Sever VM to different Azure Account

Tags: azure, active-directory, migration, virtual-machine, exchange-server

I have setup my test Exchange server on Azure VM, but now I want to use it for my production and want to move it to a different Azure account.

I cannot generalize my VM as it contains Active Directory which doesn't support generalizing.(I have tried generalizing but VM didn't boot up).

So I migrated without generalizing and with this I was able to RDP into VM but Azure showing the following error.

"guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image".

Can anyone please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, it seems we should generalize it first.

If you just want to copy this VHD to another Azure account and use that VHD to create a new VM, maybe we can use [this template](https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FAzure%2Fazure-quickstart-templates%2Ftree%2Fmaster%2F201-vm-specialized-vhd&data=02%7C01%7Cv-jianye%40microsoft.com%7C0d8decb6c3ec4f90733208d525c0e3ef%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636456432747905449&sdata=Sls3udT4bJQnuf382KDLGMabjUaHbLyB6u%2B6EX1ERDU%3D&reserved=0) to create it.

Like this:

[image]

[image]

In this way, we can use existing VHD to create new VM.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used this template to launch my exchange VM and did not get the failed error that I used to get before.

Thanks it worked.

Comment: why not just migrate it? much easier, 1 click stuff, less error prone